# Sluggishness in VS Code due to Gtk on Windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, windows-10, julia

In VS Code, when I run a Julia file, if I have included the library ProfileView via `using ProfileView`, I get the following warning.

> Warning: You are using Gtk on Windows which is currently not recommended. Your REPL/IDE and anything depending on task switches will become sluggish and much slower (up to ~85x slower).

The IDE does become very sluggish.

What should I do to fix this? JuliaPro and Atom are also very slow, and this slowness was why I switched to VS Code (the reason for the slowness may have been different, but I mention this just in case it is useful).

As suggested by the error message, I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

per the warning message you are getting, the only way to "fix" this would be to not use a Windows computer. There's nothing you can do about the slow down on Windows with respect to GTK.jl at this time.